# ResourceExhausted Error or OOM when running LSTM in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, error-handling, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm training my LSTM network in Tensorflow with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

%matplotlib inline

sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted', font_scale=1.5)

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 8

RANDOM_SEED = 42

columns = ['user','activity','timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
df = pd.read_csv('data/WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt', header = None, names = columns)
df = df.dropna()

df.head()

df.info()

##df['activity'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Training examples by activity type');
##df['user'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Training examples by user');

def plot_activity(activity, df):
    data = df[df['activity'] == activity][['x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']][:200]
    axis = data.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(16, 12), 
                     title=activity)
    for ax in axis:
        ax.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))


##plot_activity("Sitting", df)
##plot_activity("Standing", df)
##plot_activity("Walking", df)
##plot_activity("Jogging", df)


N_TIME_STEPS = 200
N_FEATURES = 3
step = 20
segments = []
labels = []
for i in range(0, len(df) - N_TIME_STEPS, step):
    xs = df['x-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    ys = df['y-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    zs = df['z-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    label = stats.mode(df['activity'][i: i + N_TIME_STEPS])[0][0]
    segments.append([xs, ys, zs])
    labels.append(label)

np.array(segments).shape

reshaped_segments = np.asarray(segments, dtype= np.float32).reshape(-1, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES)
labels = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels), dtype = np.float32)

reshaped_segments.shape
labels[0]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        reshaped_segments, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

len(X_train)
len(X_test)

N_CLASSES = 6
N_HIDDEN_UNITS = 64


def create_LSTM_model(inputs):
    W = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_FEATURES, N_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS, N_CLASSES]))
    }
    biases = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS], mean=1.0)),
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_CLASSES]))
    }

    X = tf.transpose(inputs, [1, 0, 2])
    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, N_FEATURES])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W['hidden']) + biases['hidden'])
    hidden = tf.split(hidden, N_TIME_STEPS, 0)

    # Stack 2 LSTM layers
    lstm_layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN_UNITS, forget_bias=1.0) for _ in range(2)]
    lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layers)

    outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layers, hidden, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Get output for the last time step
    lstm_last_output = outputs[-1]

    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, W['output']) + biases['output']


tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES], name="input")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_CLASSES])


pred_Y = create_LSTM_model(X)

pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(pred_Y, name="y_")

loss = -tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(pred_softmax))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred_softmax,1), tf.argmax(Y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1],dtype=float)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

batch_size = 10
total_batches = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size


for epoch in range(8):
        for b in range(total_batches):    
            offset = (b * batch_size) % (y_train.shape[0] - batch_size)
            batch_x = X_train[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
            batch_y = y_train[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
            _, c = session.run([optimizer, loss],feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y : batch_y})
            cost_history = np.append(cost_history,c)
        print("Epoch: ",epoch," Training Loss: ",c," Training Accuracy: ",\
              session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train}))
```

and the dataset I used was from http://www.cis.fordham.edu/wisdm/dataset.php:

WISDM_ar_txtv1.1_raw

However, when I run it I get a ResourceExhausted or OOM error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1350, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1329, in _run_fn
>       status, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 473, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM
>   when allocating tensor with shape[8784000,64] and type float on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
>   [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false,
>   transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Reshape, Variable/read)]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors
>   when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions
>   for current allocation info.
>
> [[Node: add_1/_15 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_9637_add_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add
>   report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current
>   allocation info.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 9, in
>   
>       session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train}))   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 895, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1128, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1344, in _do_run
>       options, run_metadata)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1363, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM
>   when allocating tensor with shape[8784000,64] and type float on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
>   [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false,
>   transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Reshape, Variable/read)]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors
>   when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions
>   for current allocation info.
>
> [[Node: add_1/_15 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_9637_add_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add
>   report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current
>   allocation info.
>
> Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py",
>   line 130, in main
>       ret = method(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py",
>   line 357, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 13, in create_LSTM_model   File
>   "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 2022, in matmul
>       a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)   File
>   "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 2799, in _mat_mul
>       name=name)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 3160, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\Chaine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1625, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating
>   tensor with shape[8784000,64] and type float on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
>   [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false,
>   transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Reshape, Variable/read)]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors
>   when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions
>   for current allocation info.
>
> [[Node: add_1/_15 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_9637_add_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add
>   report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current
>   allocation info.

What might be causing this error?

UPDATE: I ran my code in another machine and it didn't give out errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a major problem in your code. You are facing this problem  because you don't have a static graph - which means you keep adding a new graph as you are going through your for loop. If you track how you evaluate your loss value in your

```
session.run([loss]),
```

you will notice that you are running

```
pred_Y = create_LSTM_model(X)
```

part of your code multiple times as you are going through your for loop.

You don't want to do this. You should modify your code in such a way that you can pull the loss parameter from the graph without re-creating your graph.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi I ran my code in another laptop and it worked. Why is this?